# Why to avoid biginteger instantiation in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

There is a [PMD rule](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/basic.html#BigIntegerInstantiation) saying one should avoid to instantiate BigInteger or BigDecimal if there is a predefined constant.

```
BigInteger.ZERO

// instead of

new BigInteger(0)
```

Would there be any other advantage than saving a few bytes?

Comment: Its about 48 bytes. But it depends on how much its is called as to whether it matters.  If performance is critical then BigInteger may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it avoids the allocation of those few bytes and the need to collect them back later

in a tight loop that can matter

Answer (score 2):

Yes, saving a few JVM instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly performance, if you are instantiating a lot of 0s.  An alternative for long/int argument is

`BigInteger.valueOf(0)`

which returns BigInteger.ZERO when argument is 0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new object with `new BigInteger` you'd better use one static object which is created once when the BigInteger class is loaded. It is also true for using `valueOf` of all wrapper types.

Comment: Do you mean that `valueOf` uses those constants?

Comment: @deamon yep check http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29 at the bottom

Comment: @deamon Yes, `valueOf` uses a pool of the most frequently used values. For example, `BigInteger.valueOf` caches 33 values from -16 to 16, so when you invoke it for these values you'll always get the same BitInteger object for one value. `BigInteger.ZERO` is just `BigInteger.valueOf(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

By using cached values, it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.