# Why are they holding this many instances(33) even before being asked for? Where did they get the number 16 from?

Tags: java, biginteger, bigint

When I was studying about static blocks , I wanted to see its usage in java source code . so I referred java.math.BigInteger.java  . The static block there was like this

```
/**
 * Initialize static constant array when class is loaded.
 */
private final static int MAX_CONSTANT = 16;
private static BigInteger posConst[] = new BigInteger[MAX_CONSTANT+1];
private static BigInteger negConst[] = new BigInteger[MAX_CONSTANT+1];
static {
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_CONSTANT; i++) {
        int[] magnitude = new int[1];
        magnitude[0] = i;
        posConst[i] = new BigInteger(magnitude,  1);
        negConst[i] = new BigInteger(magnitude, -1);
    }
}
```

[static block code in code browser](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/lib/view/jdk7u10/java/math/BigInteger.java;nav:36548:36556%3afocused)

From this I am getting a sense that they are creating 33 BigInteger instances and holding it in posConst and negConst .
Then later when people call valueOf in [BigInteger.java:valueOf](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/lib/view/jdk7u10/java/math/BigInteger.java;nav:35145:35152%3afocused)

if value is between -16 to 16 they take from posConst and negConst and give . If it is beyond this range they create new instance .

I can understand that they are holding instances to give it readily if user asks one among that list . On what basis or probability  are they holding 33 instances . Is it not a waste of memory . Why not create when user asks and only that particular instance .

I cannot understand the trade off attained in this logic . Please help .
Am I going wrong in understanding this code . If so please help .

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674391/why-to-avoid-biginteger-instantiation-in-java/7674462#7674462
(but still does not answer the question)

Answer (score 5):

This is actually intended to *save* memory (and time spent creating objects). A program which uses BigIntegers is likely to have many copies of the same numbers, by storing just one instance of BigInteger(1), you can have hundreds of thousands of references to the number, but only have to create one object.

It's worth noting that static initialization happens when a class is referenced, so programs which don't use BigInteger will not store this array. In programs which do use BigInteger, the worst case is you're storing 33 objects you don't have to, but in the best case scenario you're saving on the creation and storage of thousands of objects by simply referring to these constants.

This is called the [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Now, why store these specific constants, and not the exact objects used in the program? The latter would require storing every BigInteger used in the program in a hash table, and checking this table every time a new BigInteger is created, which is much more expensive in memory and computation time than the existing solution. You would also have to worry about concurrent modification of the table, so locking would be involved as well. Simply put, memoizing the exact objects used in the program is too expensive to be done by default. Some programs which re-use a lot of BigIntegers outside the range of -16 to 16 will implement this themselves.

Small numbers usually occur much more often in programs, which is why these specific values were chosen to be memoized.

Comment: Does it really answer the question? You are talking about the pool where BigIntegers can be saved and reused. This is clear, but OP asks why it is created before it is really needed.

Comment: Lets look at it as per your logic . Just with the hope that user will ask number within -16 to 16 they have created 16 instances . say time taken to create an instance be a second (just for example) . you are wasting 33 seconds just because of that hope . What is the probability that he will ask within that range ? I cannot understand ..

Comment: typo in comment 2  , it is 33 instances.

Comment: The probabilities cannot be calculated, as the writers of the library had no way of knowing what programs would be written for it. However they judged the trade-off to be worthwhile because, as I mentioned, the costs of this are small (simply creating and storing 33 additional objects in the whole program. Utterly negligible.), and the potential benefits are huge.

Comment: Ya  +1 . I can understand your point ,though I cannot accept your statement "Small numbers usually occur much more often in programs" . May be if we consider it to be inefficient, may be we have to extend it and introduce our own class which suits . May be that is the reason why the class was not made "final" . May be they predicted the drawbacks . One which I found was that sum ,difference, multiply ,divide everything accepts biginteger as input , but pow doesn't .

Comment: [Small numbers are used more often in general](http://mathematicalmulticore.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/which-numbers-are-the-most-common/).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the Javadoc for `BigInteger.java:valueOf`:

```
/**
 * Returns a BigInteger whose value is equal to that of the
 * specified {@code long}.  This "static factory method" is
 * provided in preference to a ({@code long}) constructor
 * because it allows for reuse of frequently used BigIntegers.
 */
```

Yes, this does use a bit of extra memory at first, but it's a worthwhile tradeoff because it saves spending time creating often-used BigIntegers over and over (an apparently expensive operation).

But ultimately it also saves memory, since there's no reason, for example, for multiple copies of BigInteger value of 0 to exist in every place where it's used.

The reason for the choice of -16 to +16 is somewhat arbitrary, but I'm sure somebody did a bit of analysis to come up with that range.